# Where to ask questions for advanced audio automation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Maybe a short version of our problem:

We need an automated system to play audio messages on different network speaker systems.

The system should be able to receive requests for messages to play on certain speakers. The messages are already recorded and should just be played back.

So, in very basic terms, something like a soundboard for multiple speakers, but fully automated with network requests.

So far we don't have any hardware, except probably one Windows server, but I assume, we can add a dedicated server for that as well. We do not have anything that receives the audio (streams most likely).

My main questions would be:

- What hardware to get (smart oder dumb receivers?)
- Is there software available, that can do that for us and that can be remote controlled over an API?
- If there's something like that, can we monitor the functionality and detect speakers that can't be reached?
- Or would we need to write it ourselves?
- If we have to write it ourselves, what's best suited for that requirement?

Comment: Ask an audio vendor?

Comment: I doubt there is any SE you can ask on. What you need is a professional, you seem to be having a hard time even getting started.